# Travelling with a Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, internationalization

When travelling to a foreign country my notebook loads websites in that country and language. I want it to continue with my home country sites and not have it know I have changed countries. How?

Comment: You need to use a VPN. Decent ones are not free. There are many options, but one I feel pretty good recommending is privateinternetaccess.

Comment: It uses your Internet connection to determine what country you are in. But you can force it. For example instead Google.com use Google.fr

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned a VPN is needed. This will echo the web traffic.

I have read online that this might help:

https://vpnuk.net/setup/

But I have personally never used it